# Custom animated image control

Tags: c#, performance, animation, winforms

I have written the following control which allows loading a GIF from embedded resource, file, or raw `Image`.  It allows for more granular control over the direction and frames per second of animated image types.

The problem I face, is it is quite laggy during the frame switching (unlike the `PictureBox` control which doesn't offer any animation control but does animate GIFs).

Given this code and the objective, what do you think could be done to improve it's performance. Presently, it lags when animation is set to 10 FPS, and ideally, I would like user control up to 200 FPS.

```
public partial class ImageBox : UserControl
{
    private FrameDimension dimension;
    private int frameCount;
    private int currentFrame = -1;
    private int step = 1;

    private Timer timer;

    public int FrameCount { get { return FrameCount; } }

    public bool Animate { get { return timer.Enabled; } set { timer.Enabled = value; } }

    public enum AnimationDirectionEnum
    {
        Forward,
        Reverse
    }

    public AnimationDirectionEnum AnimateDirection { get; set; } 

    private int _FPS;
    public int FPS
    {
        get { return _FPS; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0 && value <= 200)
            {
                _FPS = value;
                if (_FPS > 0)
                {
                    timer.Interval = 1000 / value;
                }
                else
                {
                    timer.Interval = 2000;
                    timer.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void LoadImage(FileInfo path)
    {
        if(File.Exists(path.ToString()))
        {
            LoadImage(Image.FromFile(path.ToString()));
        }
    }

    public void LoadImage(string resource)
    {
        Stream res = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
        LoadImage(Image.FromStream(res));
    }

    public void LoadImage(Image image)
    {
        currentFrame = -1;
        BackgroundImage = image; //initialize
        dimension = new FrameDimension(BackgroundImage.FrameDimensionsList[0]); //gets the GUID
        frameCount = BackgroundImage.GetFrameCount(dimension); //total frames in the animation
    }

    public ImageBox()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new Timer();
        _FPS = 10;
        timer.Enabled = false;
        timer.Interval = 100;
        timer.Tick += AnimateFrame;
        currentFrame = -1;
    }

    private void AnimateFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        currentFrame += step;

        //if the animation reaches a boundary...
        if (currentFrame >= frameCount || currentFrame < 1)
        {
            if (AnimateDirection == AnimationDirectionEnum.Reverse)
            {
                step *= -1; //...reverse the count
                currentFrame += step; //apply it
            }
            else
            {
                currentFrame = 0; //...or start over
            }
        }
        BackgroundImage.SelectActiveFrame(dimension, currentFrame);
        Invalidate();
        //Refresh();
    }

    public Image GetFrame(int index)
    {
        if(index <= frameCount && index >= 0 && BackgroundImage != null)
        {
            BackgroundImage.SelectActiveFrame(dimension, index); //find the frame
            return (Image)BackgroundImage.Clone(); //return a copy of it
        } else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're targeting 200 FPS? Such a high number is never required and I smell a misguidance in your design.

Comment: @Mast - it is just an arbitrary maximum. The number is based on my average FPS in certain games (so I certainly have the equipment to manage it).  Instead of focusing on the peak FPS objective, lets try and focus on why even at 10 FPS, it is laggy.  A hint, the control is locking the ui when switching the image for about 50-150ms (approx) per frame.

Comment: Is there a reason you're locking the UI every frame?

Comment: The default min timer resolution is about 15.6 milliseconds (see:  [Timer-Resolution.docx](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/0/2/3027D574-C433-412A-A8B6-5E0A75D5B237/Timer-Resolution.docx)), so your 200 fps (5 ms) would require mucking around with PInvoking timeBeginPeriod/timeEndPeriod to set the faster timer interval.  You may want to look at how MS wrote the [ImageAnimator Class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/ImageAnimator.cs,5c62a859bbe32b7d) for some ideas as well; it is used by the `PictureBox Class`.

Comment: After a quick glance I suspect cloning the image on every frame change might be the bottleneck; how about storing a list of all the frames in memory and then switching between them on the timer's tick?

Comment: Why are you creating a clone at all for the `BackgroundImage`?  Just set it to the image once.  After calling `img.SelectActiveFrame`, call `this.Invalidate` to force a repaint.

Comment: I had a quick test and loading a list of frames before switching makes it faster; I think @TnTinMn solution is the best way, you avoid the cloning and don't even change the image. By the way, I would avoid doing graphics with standard WinForms controls, I would find something more fit for purpose in NuGet.

Comment: @TnTinMn - That works, but still the same problem.  I should clarify what I mean by "laggy".  When the control is on a form, try dragging the form around fast --- it is sort of sticky, and chops.  The image itself didn't lag on me.

Comment: If lag on Form move is issue, a simple fix should be to handle the parent Form's ill named `ResizeBegin` and `ResizeEnd` events to pause/restart your animation.

Comment: @TnTinMn - yes, that is more a workaround.  If I set the gif to a picturebox (where I can't control the framerate), there is no lag on form move and the animation continues during the drag process. I have traced it to when `Invalidate`, or `Refresh` are called.  Is there another way to update the GUI from a timer event that doesn't block ?

Comment: Please update your code to reflect the current status.

Comment: @TnTinMn - I updated the code example.

Comment: I made a functional prototype UC based on this concept using the GIF from your other posting.  The only way I get any jitter is when the `BackgroundImageLayout` is set to `Tile`.  The `Timer.Interval` is set to 16.